# How do I import webkit to mono

Tags: mono, gtk, webkit

Im trying to build a GTK app in mono but im not sure how i would get WebKit it into my project

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using GtkSharp;
using WebKit;
```

I get and error at the `using WebKit;` part that states

> The type or namespace name `WebKit` could not be found. Are you missing a assembly reference

I fully understand the error and what it means, however im not sure how to resolve it and get WebKit into my GTK project

*Small notice but im new to mono and don't quite know where everything is*

*Im running Fedora 36 with MonoDevelop 5.10*

Comment: Both MonoDevelop and GTK# 2 are dead. If you use the new GTK# 3, then WebKit integration is already part of it, https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp but you should use it with .NET 6.

Comment: Thanks, I ditched Mono and started using GTK#3 and now it works, Thanks.